# Mangento not Loading Page Correctly

Tags: magento, templates, configuration, loading

If I enable path hints in my Magento configuration, I notice that a lot of files are not being loaded, so the page is not displaying right. How can I fix this error?

[image: Mangento not loading page correctly]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get this, it's usually because there's a PHP error in the last block that was suppose to load. When the last block started to render (in your screenshot, novaworks/imagezoom/media.phtml), an error occurred which caused the rest of page to halt. If you're using Chrome, inspect that element and see if there are any PHP errors outputted. Make sure you have display_errors turned on:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1)
```